# Is entity data-model (.edmx files) ORM-agnostic?

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, orm

After having used NHibernate for several years, I am now learning Entity Framework for use on my next project.  At the moment, I am trying to decide between the code-first or model-first approaches.  The model-first approach appeals to me, but the result would have to be ORM-agnostic.  To this end, I am pondering the following.  Would it be possible and practical to create T4 templates that generate classes and .hbm.xml files (for use with NHibernate) from the CSDL and C-S mapping content of a .edmx file?

Answer (score 3):

No mapping is ORM agnostic because it is part of that ORM API or did you see Entity framework using NHibernate's hbm files? EDMX is XML representation of EDM (Entity Data Model) which is MS asset and it is mainly used for MS APIs. Moreover not all API for EDM processing provided by MS is accessible (internal implementation). EDMX is not ORM agnostic. The worse part is that it is even not database agnostic.

Anyway you can create any custom tool or transformation taking EDMX as input and providing other mapping as output. You just need to understand input and output format. I'm not sure if it will directly be possible with T4 but it is definitely possible. But it will not be practial. Practical is using single ORM to its full power and use tools available for that ORM.

Comment: If the EDMX is treated simply as an XML file then it is not using the Entity Framework API, correct?  I won't attempt to stay agnostic of MS APIs in general since that is the whole of .NET.

Comment: Well, I meant that NHibernate and no other ORM can use EDMX so it is not agnostic. The fact that it is XML and you can create transformation doesn't change it. I will easily write some EDMX which will not be convertible without huge effort beause it will use EF advanced features including ESQL queries. So IMHO thinking about any conversion from EDMX to something else doesn't worth it. In most cases you will create those hbm files faster manually.

Comment: What are some other ORMs that won't work with this approach and why not?  Your point about ESQL is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and practical to create T4 templates that generate classes for Fluent NHibernate from an .edmx file. I am on a project at AMD where we are doing just that. (I am not the author myself.) See: http://tom-jaeschke.blogspot.com/2011/08/use-entity-framework-and-nhibernate.html

Comment: Interesting. I'm looking at the possibility of doing the opposite - I have an established NHibernate layer (NHQueryable) for which I'd like to generate an EDMX equivalent, so that I can use certain APIs which rely on the MS EDM (eg. Microsoft.Data.OData.Query).